# scala return matrix of average pixels

Tags: scala, matrix

Here's the thing: I want to modify (and then return) a matrix of integers that is given in the parameters of the function. The funcion average (of the class MatrixMotionBlur) gives the average between the own pixel, upper, down and left pixels. Follows the following formula:

result(x, y) = (M1(x, y)+M1(x-1, y)+M1(x, y-1)+M1(x, y+1)) / 4

This is the code i've implemented so far

MatrixMotionBlur - Average function 
[image]

MotionBlurSingleThread - run
[image]

The objetive here is to apply "average" method to alter the matrix value and return that matrix. The thing is the program gives me error when I to insert the value on the matrix.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Please use proper code formatting instead of Screenshots... These screenshots leak quite a bit of information that has nothing to to with the problem at hand. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

The functional way

```
val updatedData = data.map{ outter =>
    outter(i).map{ inner =>
        mx.average(i.j)
    }
}
```

Pay attention that `Seq` is immutable collection type and you can't just modify it, you can create new, modified collection only.

By the way, why you iterate starting 1, but not 0. Are you sure you want it?

Comment: def run(data: Seq[Seq[Int]], numberOfWorkers: Int) = Future[Seq[Seq[Int]]]{

    val mx =  new MatrixMotionBlur

    var myMatrix = ofDim[Int](data.length, data(0).length)

    for(i <- 1 until  data.length-1){
      for(j <- 1 until data(i).length-1){

        val v1: Int = mx.average(data,i,j)

        println("Valor Transformado" + v1)

        myMatrix(i)(j)=v1
      }

    }


    return  myMatrix

  }

I tried to create a new toDim matrix and then update it using former matrix values. But still doesn't allow me to return the type

Comment: Array is immutable also. You need to read something about Scala collection types, good start point is https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html